# Testing that BroadcastReceiver does not receive protected broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'll try to outline this scenario as well as I can. The main question is: **how can I declare 2 receivers dynamically which both receive the same broadcast, but only one has the correct permission to receive it?** In my testing so far, both receivers get the broadcast due to my app holding the declared permission, rather than just the one.

In App A, I am sending a broadcast which I am protecting with the new permission I am defining.

In App B, I want to ensure that the broadcast from App A is in fact being protected. So I dynamically declare the 2 receivers for the same `IntentFilter`, one holding the new permission and one without. However, in App B's manifest, I of course declare `<uses-permission android:name="new permission" />`

However, both receivers are getting it, not just the one holding the permission. I assume that it's because App B itself is declared to use the permission. Here's my code:

App A manifest:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.my.custom.permission"
    android:label="my_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

App A source:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SOME_CUSTOM_ACTION);
...
sendBroadcast(intent, "com.my.custom.permission");
```

App B manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.custom.permission" />
```

App B service:

```
private BroadcastReceiver rNoPermission = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SOME_CUSTOM_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "receiver was able to receive without permission");
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver rYesPermission = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SOME_CUSTOM_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "receiver was able to receive properly with permission");
        }
    }
};

public void start() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SOME_CUSTOM_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(rNoPermission, filter); // purposely don't register with permission
    registerReceiver(rYesPermission, filter, "com.my.custom.permission", null);
}

public void end() {
    unregisterReceiver(rNoPermission);
    unregisterReceiver(rYesPermission);
}
```

Flow:

1. App A installed for Android to learn new permission
2. App B installed and run
3. App B `start()` method is called
4. Switch to App A to trigger sending the broadcast
5. See in logs that both `BroadcastReceiver`s get called
6. End test by calling `end()` method

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realized where my mistake is. Permissions are granted at the application level, not at the component level. As per Android documentation:

> To enforce a permission when sending, you supply a non-null permission argument to `sendBroadcast(Intent, String)` or `sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String, BroadcastReceiver, android.os.Handler, int, String, Bundle)`. Only receivers who have been granted this permission (by requesting it with the  tag in their AndroidManifest.xml) will be able to receive the broadcast.

(Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

and:

> Senders of an intent can verify that the recipient has a permission specifying a non-Null permission with the method call. Only **applications** with that permission will receive the intent.

(Source: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)

So as of now there doesn't appear to be a way to do what I mention above without splitting the `BroadcastReceiver`s into 2 separate apps, one using the permission and one without.